# Error during project build: SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near system_time

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to build project in MS Visual Studio 2015 from database created in SQL Server 2016.

Getting an error during project build:

> SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near system_time

There is a part in a code using system_time feature of temporal tables, like:

```
SELECT 
    'actual' tbl, * 
INTO 
    #my_table
FROM
    my_table
FOR system_time AS OF @dt
```

And Visual Studio does not recognize `system_time` as valid syntax.

`@dt` is of `datetime2` datatype.

Certainly it does work in SSMS 2016.

Set `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` to 130 did not help

Please help to resolve described issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved after additional installation of SSDT - all errors have gone now